# Why React's setState is not triggering re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I find it difficult to understand one point:
setState in ParentComponent trigger re-rendering of ChildComponent as expected, thats ok. But setState in MyProvider component does not trigger it! Why that? There is no any memoization.
You can try this story and make sure there will only 2 render messages: initial and after 6 seconds.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Context = React.createContext<number>(123);
const MyProvider: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const [, setProviderState] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setProviderState(123), 2000);
  }, []);

  return <Context.Provider value={123}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
};

export const ParentComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const [, setParentState] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setParentState(123), 6000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <MyProvider>
      <ChildComponent />
    </MyProvider>
  );
};

const ChildComponent: React.FC = () => {
  console.log("render!");
  return <div>rest tree</div>;
};

export default { title: "Test" };
```

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#:%7E:text=All%20consumers%20that%20are%20descendants%20of%20a%20Provider%20will%20re%2Drender%20whenever%20the%20Provider%E2%80%99s%20value%20prop%20changes.):

> All consumers that are descendants of a Provider will re-render
> whenever the Provider’s value prop changes

To trigger the re-render from provider, ensure that you change your value prop to be the state value (not the hardcoded value 123) like so:

```
const MyProvider: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const [providerState, setProviderState] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setProviderState(123), 2000);
  }, []);

  return <Context.Provider value={providerState}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
};
```

Note the value of `value`, in `<Context.Provider>` is changed from being the hardcoded value of *123* to the value that providerState points to.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But i not testing a context usage. I testing only the "setState" callback behavior: calling this callback should trigger a re-rendering all of subtree by default? But it didn't, because of this exception rule, right?

Comment: I guess, this rule from your link shouldn't prevent a re-rendering child after calling a setState callback on a root.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question correctly apologies. What I'm saying is your state change in context won't cause re-renders (even if you change state) if you don't include the relevant values in `<Context.Providers values={<here>}`. If a value in "values" changes, it will trigger a re-render

Comment: My question not about context value. "123" is just mocks. Question about re-rendering the subtree after setState calling. providerState not in context, this state in a component, that produce context's provider. What expected: calling setProviderState will trigger re-rendering a subtree as written in react docs. Fact: no any renders of subtree. I can't find explanation of this in docs :(

Comment: Yes I think I understand.
I know `123` is a mock value but Context will only trigger re-render if a value in the <Context.Provider *value={here}* changes. If you do not include something in the value prop, it won't trigger a re-render (even if you change state) if the value changing is not in the value prop passed to <Context.Provider>. In your example, since value is hardcoded, setProviderState won't cause re-render since providerState is not in the `value={}` prop

Comment: But why setParentState trigger child re-render, and setProviderState not? What difference, have ideas?

Comment: Based on the link I shared - consumer's of **Provider** specifically won't cause a re-render if not changing a value in `value=`. Your setParentState triggers a re-render because it is a regular component but a provider is not. So if you change your value={123} to the state variable you have (like I suggest in the code above), does it re-render?

Comment: Aa, i understand. It use it's children, but it children not in react component tree there. Omg, my bad. Have stupid, sorry :)
Thanks for answers!

Comment: No problem! Glad you figured it out :D

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setParentState(123), 6000);
  }, [setProviderState]);
```

Put your set state inside [] as shown in the code above. Whenever your set state changes, it will re render.